# Having problems using drop-down menu variables to create a table filled with these variables in PHP

Tags: php, post, drop-down-menu, tabular

I am a PHP beginner and I am stuck on an assignment for school. I have to create 6 different drop down menus (num1 , num2 , num3 , num4 , rows , columns) each with the numbers 1 through 10 in it. I then have make sure the form is submitted, and only when it is submitted all perfectly, then I have to use the variables to create a table based on even and odd numbers.

```
<form method="post" action="prelab2.php">
<select name="num1">

<option>Pick one</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>

</select>
```

Above is the drop-down menu, now this is where I am really stuck.

```
<?php
$_POST['submit'];
$num_1=$_POST['num1'];
$num_2=$_POST['num2'];
$num_3=$_POST['num3'];
$num_4=$_POST['num4'];
$rows=$_POST['rows'];
$cols=$_POST['cols'];
?>
```

I figured out how to $_POST the variables, but how can I take these variables (only on submit) and turn it into a table?

[This is the link to my assignment](http://gblearn.com/comp1230/labs/prelabs/prelab2.pdf)

Comment: Hint: you could loop through your `$_POST` values and create the `<table>` tag elements (`<tr>`, `<td>`) as you go...

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. `$_POST['submit']` is not neccesary. In your PHP script, create the HTML for the table, and then `<?php echo $num_1; ?>` (or the others) where needed. The HTML must be outside the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

A line like `$_POST['submit'];` has no side effect... That is, it does nothing. You're just reading the variable value and not storing it anywhere.

What you're searching for seems to be [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.echo.php). It writes content to the output, in your case the HTML page.

In a template-style, you can use it this way:

```
<?php
    // initial PHP code (reading form value, etc.)

    $title = 'Foo';

    // after the closing tag, starts the output
?>
<html>
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>

    <!-- remaining of your HTML -->
</html>
```

Notice the PHP `echo` statement embeded into the HTML markup.

So now, you just have to compose your HTML page as intended, using your own variables...

Answer (score 0):

Start here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

```
<select>
  <option value="n1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="n2">Saab</option>
  <option value="n3">Opel</option>
  <option value="n...">Audi</option>
</select>

<?php $n1 = $_POST['n1']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
//check if form is submitted
echo '<table style="border:colapse">'; //css trick to make nicer borders

//get post vars

$num_1=$_POST['num1'];
$num_2=$_POST['num2'];
$num_3=$_POST['num3'];
$num_4=$_POST['num4'];

//put number values in array

$nums=array($num_1,$num_2,$num_3,$num_4);

//sort array -> we will need it for outpu

sort($nums);


$rows=$_POST['rows'];
$cols=$_POST['cols'];

for($i=0;$i<$rows;$i++) 



{
//print rows in loop
echo '<tr>';

for($j=1;$j<=$cols;$j++) 

//now print colums -> starting from one!

{


echo '<td style="border:1px solid black;width:100px;height:20px">';

//modulo operator, to check if we are inside even or odd column

if($j % 2 == 0) {



foreach($nums as $num)

// loop thorough array of numbers

{

//if number is even -> print it 

    if($num % 2==0) {

        echo $num;

    }




}   


}

else  {

    //if we are in odd row





    foreach($nums as $num)

{

    //print odd numbers
    if($num % 2 !=0) {

        echo $num;

    }




}   

}





echo '</td>';   


}



echo '</tr>';  






}






echo '</table>';




}
```

P.S. I know that this could get many down votes, but... :)